# Unable to receive full FIX message upon QuickFIX/J version upgrade 1.6.3 to 1.6.4

Tags: quickfixj

I am able to receive my FIX message successfully in fromApp() method but when I am on quickfix version 1.6.3.
As soon as I change quickfix version to 1.6.4, I am not receiving part of my message.

The message I receive on 1.6.3
8=FIX.4.4__9=176__35=V__34=283__49=K3FIX__52=20240206-11:19:44.484__56=acceptor-dev__142=192.000.8.001__262=KL07181EBBE34530982ECAF18982BCGH__263=1__271=1__4567=2M__146=1__55=ABC/MNQ__83=FBSFxR4__10=201__

The message I receive on 1.6.4
8=FIX.4.4__9=139__35=V__34=2__49=K3FIX__52=20240206-10:25:52.758__56=acceptor-dev__142=192.000.8.001__146=1__262=KH4B989277CE4A97A079619BF58E8BFT__263=1__10=101__

So you see after 263=1, I am missing on few fields.
These are the messages logged in fromApp() method.

Please note I have nto changed anything from 1.6.3 to 1.6.4 except this change of version.

I am using FIX 4.4 in both and using below 2 properties as well:
fix.acceptor.useDataDictionary=Y
fix.acceptor.dataDictionary=FIX44.xml

I verfied source is sending correct message in both cases.
I am trying to log the messages in fromApp method and above are those messages.
Verified FIX4.4 in both cases and data dictionary props are same in both cases too.
I am expecting information  "4567=2M__146=1__55=ABC/MNQ__83=FBSFxR4" in my message after 1.6.4 upgrade.

Edit:

I have those props in my application.properties

```
fix.acceptor.validateFieldsOutOfOrder=N
fix.acceptor.allowUnknownMsgFields=Y
```

Edit2:
below is my FX44.xml

```
<fix major="4" minor="4">
        <header>
        </header>
        <trailer>
        </trailer>
        <messages>
            <message name="KDRequest" msgtype="V" msgcat="app">
                <group name="NRS" required="N"> 
                    <field name="KDESize" required="N" />
                    <field name="DValue" required="N" />
                </group>
            </message>
            <message name="KDSFull" msgtype="W"
                msgcat="app">
                <group name="NoMDEntries" required="Y">
                    <field name="KDESize" required="N" />
                    <field name="DValue" required="N" />
                </group>
            </message>
        </messages>
        <components />
        <fields>
            <field number="271" name="KDESize" type="QTY" />
            <field number="4567" name="DValue" type="STRING" />
        </fields>
    </fix>
```

Comment: This is QuickFIX/J (so Java), right?

Comment: Yes right!! Its Java

Answer (score 1):

Check that the dictionary for message type V/MarketDataRequest containts the tags that you receive in the message.

E.g. tags 271 and 4567 are NOT part of the standard V message. You need to add these tags to the dictionary (preferred) or set the following options to have the message accepted:

```
ValidateUnorderedGroupFields=N
AllowUnknownMsgFields=Y
```

Edit: IIRC we improved some thing in validating unknown fields. If your case worked with QFJ 1.6.3 then it was most probably a bug. ;)

Comment: I have added tags 271 and 4567 already in my FX44.xml. 
You mean the properties:
fix.acceptor.validateUnorderedGroupFields = N
fix.acceptor.allowUnknownMsgFields = Y

Is that correct?

Comment: Did you add the tags to the message V? Where? Could you update your question with the relevant part from the dictionary? About the properties: don't know which software you are using that formats the properties that way. Originally QFJ uses the properties that I mentioned in my answer.

Comment: I have edited to post to add more information, could not provided the whole xml, only provided a part from it.

Comment: What is the value of "NRS"?

Comment: Its 146
<field number="146" name="NRS" type="NUMINGROUP" />

Comment: IIRC we improved some thing in validating unknown fields. If your case worked with QFJ 1.6.3 then it was most probably a bug. --> By this do you mean bug from QF upgrade ?

Comment: Bug in the 1.6.3 version. Could you update your question with the position of tags 55 and 83 in the NRS group of the KDRequest message? I'm pretty sure that the order of tags in the dictionary is different from what you receive on the wire. Is there an output of the message before it is passed to fromApp()?